# can't change h1 font-size in print preview

Tags: html, css, media-queries, print-preview

I can't change h1 font-size in print preview. although every other property works, the font size doesn't work.

```css
body{
 margin: 1%;
 padding:1%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
 font-size: 100%;
 min-width: 500px;

}
header, footer{
  background-color:#0066FF;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
}
header h1{
 font-size: 3rem;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);;

}

section{
  margin:1%;
    padding:1%;
}

nav a{
 display:block;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 35px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 2%;
 margin: 1%;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
 color:rgba(255,0,0,.7);;
}


.myClass{
 margin: 0em 1em;
 padding:.75em;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: .25%;

 /* Safari and Chrome */
 -webkit-column-count:3;
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 column-count:3;

}



ol{
 list-style:upper-roman;
 margin:1em;
}
img{
 display: none;
}

footer{
 clear: both;
 text-align:center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 img{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 4%;
 }

 section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
 }
 #left {
  width: 20%;
 }

 #center {
  width : 70%;
 }

 #center div:last-of-type{
  width: 100%;
  padding:.75em;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0em 1em;
 }
 h2 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
 }
 h1::after {
  content: "(I guess...)";
 }

 h3 {
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bolder;

 }

 #center div p {
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
 }

 header , footer {
  background-color: initial;
 }

 footer {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
 }

 footer p {
  text-align: left;
 }


}

@media print {

 nav a {
 display:block;
 background-color: white;
 border: 0;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 }

  h1 {

  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

}
```

```html
<!-- 
Create a stylesheet that will style the page 
as it appears in the example. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Responsive Design Lab</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css"/>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
</head>
<!--  DO NOT CHANGE ANY PART OF THIS HTML CODE!!! -->

<header>
 <h1> Web Design is Awesome!!!</h1>
 <nav>
  <a href="http://www.umich.edu/">University of Michigan</a>
  <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/">Intro to Web Design</a>
 </nav>
  </header>

  <footer>
   <p>Sample code for Responsive Design .<br/> Colleen van Lent</p>
  </footer>
<!-- DO NOT CHANGE ANY PART OF THIS HTML CODE!!! -->
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know it is NOT working? Printers often have a different resolution. Try first setting the font size to something ridiculous like 35px or 50px to make sure.

Comment: Looks like a specificity problem. Try `header h1 {font-size: 16px;}` in your media print query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using em, px, or a a percent value.

```
h1 {
font-size: 24px;
font-size: 200%;
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

The percentage will depend on what the default text size is.
Usually the default size is 16px.

Comment: A `rem` value is fine too

Comment: Is it supported in the browser you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem for H1. It turned out that for me normalize.css was overriding the font-size in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css for print mode:

```
@media print{
   h1{....}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add !important in front of the h1 property value so that the browser does not override the value in print preview.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).